# How to use variable as terraform provider alias?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using terraform 0.14.8 and my requirement is to set AWS provider alias as a variable. My code block is as follow,

```
provider "aws" {
    region = var.aws_region
    alias = var.aws_region
}
```

I'm getting an error as below,

```
An alias must be a valid name. A name must start with a letter or underscore and may contain only letters, digits, underscore, and dashes.
```

This is how my variables.tf file looks

```
    variable "aws_region"{
    default = "eu-west-2"
    }
```

Any idea on workaround to solve this? I strictly need to use terrafrom version `~>0.14`

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its **not possible**. Alias must be explicitly defined and can't be a variable.